# What is combination of inequality?

Tags: calculus, inequality

I have variable $m=m_0+m_1$. In which,
\begin{cases}
m_0<n_0,   \\
m_1 \ge n_1,
\end{cases}

Is it correct to combine two inequality to one as follows?
$$n_0+n_1 > m \ge n_1$$

Second thing, if I have 
\begin{cases}
m_0 \ge n_0,   \\
m_1 \ge n_1,
\end{cases}

Is it correct to combine two inequality to one as follows?
$$m \ge n_0+n_1$$

Answer (score 0):

(1). No, you cannot.

Take $m_0=2$, $n_0=3$, $m_1=999$, $n_1=3$.

(2). Yes, you can.

We have $m-n_0-n_1=(m_0-n_0)+(m_1-n_1) \ge 0$

Comment: Thank you. Do you know which condition to make above condition $n_0+n_1 > m \ge n_1$